# Stop Handbrake showing filenames in Text on 1st second of video

Tags: video, conversion, handbrake

When I am creating videos using the Handbrake software, it puts the filename I am using in white text on the start of the video.

Is there a setting to stop this or some way around this?

I would like to create some high-quality files and do not want the filename like this to mess it up! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Are you sure that it is Handbrake adding the text and not the media player showing the file name as it starts playing? I know that sounds obvious, but I've seen that trip people up before.

Comment: I'm with Michael on this one, VLC used to do that to me and it drove me mad until I figured out how to turn it off. There's very little chance this is coming from Handbrake!

Comment: Thanks - you guys were right. I feel dumb right now!